# Probability of rolling a pair of dice

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose we have two fair dice and rolled them.

Let

- $A$ be the event "the sum of the two dice is equal to $3$";
- $B$ be the event "the sum of the two dice is equal to $7$";
- $C$ be the event "at least one dice shows $1$".

How to calculate $P(A \mid C)$?

In this case can we say that $A$ and $C$ are independent? Can we say that $B$ and $C$ are independent?

Comment: I don't see how $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ can be independent, since they're mutually exclusive and each has non-zero probability.  Did you mean something else?

Comment: Dice is already plural. The singular is die. So it's one die, 2 dice, 3 dice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(C)$ is actually $\frac{11}{36}$ – $11$ of the $36$ possible rolls show at least one 1 (don't forget to consider the double-1 case!). $P(A\cap C)=\frac2{36}$ since only 1-2 and 2-1 have at least one 1 and sum to $3$. Thus
$$P(A|C)=\frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)}=\frac{2/36}{11/36}=\frac2{11}$$

Comment: Thank you. Can I say that $P(B|C)=\frac{2}{11}$?

Comment: @AliJ Yes, since $P(B\cap C)=P(A\cap C)$.

Answer (score 3):

If one of the dices shows $1$ then there are only two ways to get $3.$ If both the dices show $1$ then there is no chance of getting $3.$ So the required probability is $\frac {2} {11}.$ Because when $C$ has already occurred then the reduced sample space has $11$ elements where at least one of the events is $1$ which are $$\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1) \}$$  and only two of them suit your purpose which are $$\{(1,2),(2,1) \}.$$

Comment: You mean that $P(A|C)=\frac{1}{18}$?

Comment: May you please help about $P(B|C)$?

Comment: Same thing happens for $P(B \mid C).$

Comment: Can't we use the rule $P(A|C)=\frac{P(A.C)}{P(A)}$

Comment: Try to think it on your own. If the event $C$ has already occured then in how many ways can the event $B$ occur?

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct...

Comment: What is the meaning of the event $A \mid C$?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel what's my mistake then?

Comment: That was before your edit; you are now correct.

Comment: Yeah! I have just seen the horrible mistake that I have made. Thank you very much @Parcly Taxel for pointing me that out.